# Gtkmm getting label color

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, gtkmm

I do not have a code error, I have just looked everywhere and cannot figure out how to do this. I want to get the color of a Gtk::widget, the Gtk::label. I can override the color of a label like this: l.override_color( c, l.get_state_flags() ); , but I have no idea how to get that color back from the label, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to set and get the color of a label:

```
// Set Color
Gtk::Label label("some label");
label.override_color (Gdk::RGBA("red"), Gtk::STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);

// Get Color
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> stylecontext = label.get_style_context();
Gdk::RGBA color = stylecontext->get_color(Gtk::STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);
std::cout << color.to_string(); // Display color as "rgb(x, x, x)"
```